# Starting a new web projects

Tags: web, frameworks

I`m starting a new website project, and I would like to hear your experience and recommendations for the correct tools to be used. I have no limitations, aka open source, commercial, languages, etc.

Website features:

- User generated content
- Administrator content managment
- Custom API for frontal and 3rd party usage of the website content
- Selling physical and digital products

There are a lot of frameworks out there, such as MVC, Symphony, django, drupal and many more.
I would like to here from first hands experience what worked best for you, and more importantly what didn't.

Comment: this is a) most probably a duplicate, b) a much too broad question, which everyone will answer differently (you don't even specify a programming language), and c), as you are asking for opinions and not a single correct answer, you should mark it "community wiki".

Comment: i always search for duplicates, haven't found one.

Answer (score 1):

Languages that I suggest to you:

- [PHP](http://php.net)
- ASP.Net
- HTML
- [Python](http://python.org)
- Javascript
- [Java](http://sun.com)

Products:

- Microsoft Visual Studio
- [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org)
- [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org)
- [Apache](http://apache.org)
- ViM Or your favorite text editor

If you want to choose a framework do like this:

- Python - Django
- ASP.Net - MVC, LINQ, WPF, Silverlight, .Net in general...
- PHP - Zend Framework
- Java - Struts

I also suggest you to read some books about these suggestions that I gave to you. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use DotNetNuke. It is webforms based but is stable, with rich functionality and vibrant community.

Answer (score 0):

it really depends upon you

I recently finished a project & used Java Struts 2 & MySQL. Simple & clean it went well.

Before that I did a project in Java Tapestry, Spring & Hibernate and MySQL as a database.

The thing is that you should keep things simple & use the tool/framework you are best with & plus consider what level of complexity is required by the problem domain.

Sometimes simple Servlets & JSP would suffice well you wont need any fancy frameworks.

The same goes for .NET & PHP or Ruby developers.